# Django - uploading several images at the time

Tags: django

I need your help in such question:

This is my models.py:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Локация", default=u'')
    photos = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos', null=True)
```

This is my forms.py:

```
class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ['name', 'photos']
```

This is my views.py:

```
class AddLocationPageView(FormView):
    template_name = 'add_location.html'
    form_class = LocationForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(AddLocationPageView, self).form_valid(form)
```

I need to have possibility of uploading several photos at the time.
How can I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: You need to learn about [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.models.BaseModelFormSet)

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm assuming you're using a relational database and your model field name is 'photos' you'll want more than one photo per location.

You can do something like:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    full_size = models.ImageField()
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()
    location = models.ForeignKey('app_label.Location', related_name='photos')
```

and remove the image field from the Location model.

To upload multiple photos, you'll want to use a [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/). Depending on the interface you want, you'll probably want to use a [model formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) so the photos get their location_id set properly.

With your form, all you need to do is use the formset_factory function that you can call in your view (probably in get_context_data).

Handling the formset in your view involves some logic wrangling but there is a project called [django-extra-views](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views) that implements the form with a formset logic, again, depending on the interface you're going for here.

If you want to just add photos to a pre-existing location, that is much simpler: just include the model_formset with a location object.